# Image formats in a directory

Tags: matlab

I have a piece of code

```
imgPath = 'F:\SIFT\images\'; 
dCell = dir([imgPath '*.jpg']);
```

Here i open a directory and get a list of all the images of type jpg in the dCell but what i really want is not just jpg but even other image formats like png or tiff,etc to be considered...please help! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your folder, `F:\SIFT\images\` contains only the requisite image files, you could simply use:

```
imgPath = 'F:\SIFT\images\';    %Specifies the directory path as a string.
dCell = dir(imgPath);    %Gets all entries in the directory; similar to `dir` command in Windows or the `ls` command in linux.

%By default, the first two output entries of `dir` are `.` and `..` which refer to the current and parent directories respectively.
dCell = dCell(3:end);    %Eliminates the default dir entries `.` and `..` by truncating the first two array elements.
```

Now the results can be accessed as:

```
dCell(1)    %Entry corresponding to the first file.
dCell(2)    %Entry corresponding to the second file.
```

and so on.

Each output entry of `dCell` is a `struct` with the following fields:

```
name
date
bytes
isdir
datenum
```

To get an individual field, use:

```
dCell.name
```

and so on.

To get an individual field of a particular output `struct`, use:

```
dCell(1).name
dCell(3).date
```

and so on.

For more related information, you can try `help dir` and `help struct`.

Comment: can you please explain me the code...i dunno much about matlab

Comment: @aushima: Sure. I'll put in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to build up the array yourself:

```
imgPath = 'F:\SIFT\images\'; 
dCell = dir([imgPath '*.jpg']); 
dCell = {dCell; dir([imgPath '*.gif'])};
dCell = {dCell; dir([imgPath '*.jpg'])};
%etc...
```

I'm not 100% on if the above should be in `[]` or `{}`, i.e. might be `dCell = [dCel; dir([imgPath '*.gif'])];`